# Fetch audio files based on File size in android

Tags: android

I basically want to fetch all the songs in an android device based on the file size that I specify. I am using the following query that returns me all the songs.

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
music_column_index=musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
```

But I don't know how to specify the condition where file size (say `file_size` should be more than `x` and less than `y`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int minFileSize = 1000;
int maxFileSize = 100000;
String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE + " between " + minFileSize + " and " + maxFileSize;
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, where, null, null);
```